# Check if value is in array for ng-if within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat looping through a list of wines retrieved from an API. I also have a array variable containing all wine ids that have been added to favorites fetched from database. I want to be able to display an "Add To Favorites" button if the user has not yet added a specific result wine from the list. To do this I thought I would do something like:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="wine in wines">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{ wine.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ wine.Appellation.Name }}</td>
    <td>${{ wine.PriceMin }} - ${{ wine.PriceMax }}</td>
    <td>
        <!-- If wine.Id is not yet in the array of all favorite ids, display "Add Button" -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" ng-click="addToFavorites(wine.Id)" ng-if="favorites.indexOf(wine.Id) !> -1"> Add </a>
        <!-- Else Display Already Added -->
        <span ng-if="favorites.indexOf(wine.Id) > -1">Added</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my JS:

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.favorites = [];
    var getAllFavorites = function(){
        $http.get("/home/getAllFavoriteIds").success(function(response) {
            angular.forEach(response, function(r) {
                $scope.favorites.push(r);
            });
        });
    };
});
```

I am new to .indexOf() so I am thinking maybe that is the problem. But Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: here is a working example refer it :) http://plnkr.co/edit/FVMVbKH3DpSx2yMlcSiy?p=preview

Comment: I am getting close, but now they all come out as false. Even though I entered a product_id into my favorites database.

Comment: never mind! I had to change the id value to string. id = id.toString()

Answer (score 31):

You can use [angular-filter's *contains* filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#contains):

```
<span ng-if="favorites | contains:wine.Id">Added</span>
```

or write your own filter that does the same:

```
angular.module('module').filter('contains', function() {
  return function (array, needle) {
    return array.indexOf(needle) >= 0;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend you to move this logic to controller an keep your view as clean as possible:

```
   $scope.isFavorites = function(id) {
       return $scope.favorites.indexOf(id) !== -1;
   }
```

And your view should be:

```
<!-- If wine.Id is not yet in the array of all favorite ids, display "Add Button" -->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" ng-click="addToFavorites(wine.Id)" ng-if="!isFavorites(wine.Id)">Add</a>
<!-- Else Display Already Added -->
<span ng-if="isFavorites(wine.Id)>Added</span>
```

Comment: You should be able to skip the "|| false" and just do a "return ($scope.favorites.indexOf(id) > -1);". Slightly less code :)

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to change

```
favorites.indexOf(wine.Id) !> -1
```

into

```
favorites.indexOf(wine.Id) < 0
```

Comment: indexOf  *never* returns anything less than -1

Comment: Right, my fault it should be <0

Answer (score 1):

`favorites.indexOf(wine.Id) !> -1` does not look like a proper angular expression. Note that when you have expressions in your templates, only some basic javascript conditionals are allowed. See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) for what is possible.

Instead of having a list of all wines and a list with favorite wines, you better extend the list with all wines with a boolean property `isFavorite`. This is also better for performance, since it does not need to search for the wine in the second list every iteration.

In the reponse callback loop (quick and dirty):

```
var index = $scope.favorites.indexOf(r.id);
if(index > -1) {
  $scope.favorites[index].isFavorite = true;
} // else isFavorite is undefined, which is falsy
```

Array operations like this can be done more elegantly with [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) or [Lodash](http://lodash.com).

Note that if you have an object with wines (ids as key), wines can be retrieved by id instead of lookup by index every time. `ngRepeat` supports objects just like arrays.

In your template:

```
<!-- If wine.Id is not yet in the array of all favorite ids, display "Add Button" -->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" ng-click="addToFavorites(wine.Id)" ng-if="!wine.isFavorite"> Add </a>
<!-- Else Display Already Added -->
<span ng-if="wine.isFavorite">Added</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

!> is not valid. ! can only be used with =, or with a boolean value. Use

```
favorites.indexOf(wine.Id) == -1
```

indexOf returns -1 if it can't find the element in the array.
Thanks for the correction. I was stuck on !>

Comment: I think it should be `favorites.indexOf(wine.Id) == -1`

Comment: @Vohuman, K.Toress is right. There will never be a case of < -1.